# Getting the class label using DynamicTimeWarping using Accord.NET

Tags: machine-learning, accord.net

I'm developing a project in which I need to do gesture recognition.
After searching for a way to do this I came across dynamic time warping.
To try this idea, and since my project is in C#, I decided to try Accord.NET.
Before I tried this out in my project, I created a clean project and modified the example on Accord.NET's documentation, that can be found here:

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Kernels_DynamicTimeWarping.htm

So, what I'm trying right now, is to train my algorithm with a set of learning data (composed of the gestures swipe right, swipe left and double tap) and then, use the same examples in the learning data to see if the algorithm is identifying the correct gesture. The values are just an exemple, not the real deal.

The documentation is not very clear on how to do this, since the Decide method used on the example only returns a boolean. 
I've searched the documentation for a way to identify the correct class but to no avail.

The only thing I've found was the following line, but what it returns is an int value of 0 or 1, instead of a boolean:

var res1 = ((IClassifier)svm.ToMulticlass()).Decide(sequences[0]);

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to correctly identify the gesture?
This is my first attempt at machine learning and Accord.NET, so this is all absolutelly new to me.
The example code can be found bellow.

```
namespace DynamicTimeWarpingExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double[][][] sequences =
            {
                new double[][] // Swipe left
                {
                    new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 
                    new double[] { 1, 2, 1 }, 
                    new double[] { 1, 2, 2 }, 
                    new double[] { 2, 2, 2 }, 
                },

                new double[][] // Swipe right
                {
                    new double[] { 1, 10, 6 }, 
                    new double[] { 1, 5, 6 }, 
                    new double[] { 6, 7, 1 }, 
                },

                new double[][] // Double tap
                {
                    new double[] { 8, 2, 5 }, 
                    new double[] { 1, 50, 4 }, 
                }
            };


            int[] outputs =
            {
                    0,  // Swipe left
                    1,  // Swipe right
                    2  // Double tap
            };

            var smo = new SequentialMinimalOptimization<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
            {
                Complexity = 1.5,

                Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(alpha: 1, degree: 1)
            };

            var svm = smo.Learn(sequences, outputs);

            bool[] predicted = svm.Decide(sequences);

            double error = new ZeroOneLoss(outputs).Loss(predicted); // error will be 0.0

            var res1 = ((IClassifier<double[][], int>)svm.ToMulticlass()).Decide(sequences[0]); // returns 0

            var res2 = ((IClassifier<double[][], int>)svm.ToMulticlass()).Decide(sequences[1]); // returns 1

            var res3 = ((IClassifier<double[][], int>)svm.ToMulticlass()).Decide(sequences[2]); // returns 1
        }
    }
}
```

***************** New Version *****************

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[][][] sequences =
    {
        new double[][] // Swipe left
        {
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
            new double[] { 1, 2, 1 },
            new double[] { 1, 2, 2 },
            new double[] { 2, 2, 2 },
        },

        new double[][] // Swipe right
        {
            new double[] { 1, 10, 6 },
            new double[] { 1, 5, 6 },
            new double[] { 6, 7, 1 },
        },

        new double[][] // Double tap
        {
            new double[] { 8, 2, 5 },
            new double[] { 1, 50, 4 },
        }
    };


    int[] outputs =
    {
            0,  // Swipe left
            1,  // Swipe right
            2  // Double tap
    };

    var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
    {
        // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
        //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
        Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>
        {
            Complexity = 1.5,
            Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(alpha: 1, degree: 1),
            //UseKernelEstimation = true
        }
    };

    // Learn a machine
    var machine = teacher.Learn(sequences, outputs);

    // Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
    var calibration = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
    {
        Model = machine, // We will start with an existing machine

        // Configure the learning algorithm to use Platt's calibration
        Learner = (param) => new ProbabilisticOutputCalibration<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
        {
            Model = param.Model // Start with an existing machine
        }
    };

    // Configure parallel execution options
    calibration.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;

    // Learn a machine
    calibration.Learn(sequences, outputs);

    double decision1, decision2, decision3, decision4, decision5, decision6;


    var res1 = machine.Probability(sequences[0], out decision1); // decision 0 - Probability 0.78698604216159851 - Score 1
    var res2 = machine.Probability(sequences[1], out decision2); // decision 1 - Probability 0.67246889837875257 - Score 1
    var res3 = machine.Probability(sequences[2], out decision3); // decision 2 - Probability 0.78698604216159851 - Score 1


    var newGesture1 = new double[][]
    {
        new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
        new double[] { 1, 2, 1 },
        new double[] { 1, 2, 2 },
        new double[] { 2, 2, 2 },
    };

    var newGesture2 = new double[][]
    {
        new double[] { 1, 10, 6 },
        new double[] { 1, 5, 6 },
        new double[] { 6, 7, 1 },
    };

    var newGesture3 = new double[][]
    {
        new double[] { 8, 2, 5 },
        new double[] { 1, 50, 4 },
    };

    var res5 = machine.Score(newGesture1, out decision5); // decision 0 - Probability 0.35577588944247057 - Score 0.051251948605637254
    var res6 = machine.Score(newGesture2, out decision6); // decision 1 - Probability 0.40733908994050544 - Score 0.19912250476931792
    var res4 = machine.Score(newGesture3, out decision4); // decision 2 - Probability 0.71853321355842836 - Score 0.816934034911964
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/tree/master/Samples/MachineLearning/Gestures%20(SVMs)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a binary classifier for a problem that actually involves multiple classes.

In your case, instead of doing:

```
var smo = new SequentialMinimalOptimization<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()      
{
    Complexity = 1.5,
    Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(alpha: 1, degree: 1)
};

var svm = smo.Learn(sequences, outputs);
```

You would want to wrap this binary learning problem into a multi-class learning using

```
// Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
{
    // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
    //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
    Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>
    {
        Complexity = 1.5,
        Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(alpha: 1, degree: 1)
    };
}

// Learn a  machine
var svm = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
```

Comment: Thank wou Cesar, a response from the creator of Accord.Net himself :)
This couldn't have come at a better time.
I'll give it a try this week and mark it as the accepted answer if it works.

Comment: This is the right solution.
Another line that must be changed is this:

bool[] predicted = svm.Decide(sequences);

to this:

int[] predicted = svm.Decide(sequences);

Comment: Hi again Ceaser, just a quick question.
Let's say I have a touch pad and I want to reject accidental gestures.
Is there a way to know the "certainty" of a decision?
For instance in a kNN classifier it's possible to get this by passing a variable on the Compute method:

var computedExerciseClass = knn.Compute(inputs, out certainty);

Using a similar approach I could accept the result of the Decide method if the certainty was above of a certain threshold.

Comment: You can use the .Probability or .Score methods of the SVM. If you are using SequentialMinimalOptimization, you have to calibrate the machine first using [ProbabilisticOutputCalibration](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_Learning_ProbabilisticOutputCalibration.htm) (please see the second example in the linked page). Afterwards, you will be able to get both the decision and the probability of this decision using the method ```Probability(input_vector, out decided_class)```.

Comment: Since the response is too big I'll have to break it in a few posts.
I've tried using the second example on your documentation page but if I use "UseKernelEstimation = true", I get an exception "Kernel type does not support estimation." on var machine = teacher.Learn(sequences, outputs);
I'm using a DynamicTimeWarping Kernel.
If I remove that line the exception is gone, the thing is that I get some weird results that I believe might not be related to this.
To help me better explain what's happening I edited my original post and added the new version of the code at the bottom of it.

Comment: Let's say I calculate the probability of the first gesture using multiclassSVM.Probability(sequences[0], out decision1);
This is giving me the right decision, although the probability is only around 0.78.
If after this I try to evaluate sequences[0] again I get the same result, as expected.
Now comes the weird part, if I try to create a new instance of a sequence and use the same exact values as sequences[0],
the probability lowers to around 0.36.

Comment: If I use Score instead of Probability I get a similar behaviour. If I score sequences[0] multiple times I always get the value 1, but if I create a new instance with the exact same values I get a score of 0.05.
I added the exact values as comments on the code, as you can see the instances named newGestureX are getting different values.
Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Andre, thanks a lot for the example, can I kindly ask if you could please open a new issue at the project issue tracker with the code your are using. This might be an issue with the DynamicTimeWarp kernel class. 

By the way, you don't have to set UseKernelEstimation if you don't want to. The second example was meant to show how the  ```ProbabilisticOutputCalibration``` class can/should be used after learning with SMO, but the setting the UseKernelEstimation property is actually entirely optional.